# Not sure if five of them

Tags: ambiguity, quantifiers

> a. I don't know if five of my friends are still alive or not.
>
> b. I am not sure that five of my friends are still alive.

Aren't these sentences ambiguous?

I see two possibilities

> 1. There are five of my friends who might be dead as far as I know.  I have five specific friends in mind. As regards those five, I don't know if they are alive.
> 2. As far as I know, maybe only four (or fewer) of my friends are alive.  I don't have specific people in mind. It is possible that I have fewer than five living friends.

---

> c. I don't know if most of my friends are still alive or not.
>
> d. I am not sure that most of my friends are still alive.

Aren't these sentences ambiguous?

I see these two possibilities

> 3. As regards most of my friends, I don't know if they are alive or not. I have specific friends in mind. I don't know if they are alive or not. The list of those specific friends is the 'most of my friends' I am talking about.
> 4. As far as I know it is possible that most of my friends are not alive. (I don't have specific friends in mind.)

Comment: You are correct.

Comment: I suppose that if we are strict, these are equivocal interpretations, however personally I would suppose the first interpretation is the common one.  The second meaning would be further specified by adding "[even](http://edl.byu.edu/lexicon/term/555257)" in the sense of "at least". I lack further proof or explanations though.

Comment: If you specifically specify "five of your friends" one *must* assume that you have 5 *specific* friends in mind: Why would you mention "five" if your intended meaning was No.2?  I don't think there is any difference between c. & d. as to whether you have specific friends in mind.  In **all** cases "or not" is superfluous.

Answer (score 1):

Most people would find it emotionally difficult to discuss the number of their friends who might be dead.

Given two people, the older of the two people would be more likely to contemplate how many of their friends were still alive than the the younger of the two people.

Correcting the grammar of an old person who asks you which of their friends are still alive is considered to be unethical or immoral behavior.

This question which I am responding to (on the stack exchange website) is border-line diabolical. However, I have chosen to answer the question anyway.

---

There are some ambiguities present in at least some of your sentence-examples.

If you want to reduce the ambiguousness of the sentences which you write in the future, then I reccomend emulating the style of English seen in papers published on the subject of mathematics.

Mathematicians use phrases similiar to the following:

- "exactly five"
- "at least one"
- "at least five"

The following sentences are less ambigous than examples of sentences about friends dying which you presented:

1. The last time I checked, I had exactly five friends who were still alive. I am not sure which of these friends are still alive.
2. Does there exist a set of five people ***A*** and  does there exist a time ***t*** such that time ***t*** was in the past, and at time ***t*** every person in set ***A*** was a friend of mine, and for every person ***p*** in set ***A*** person ***p*** is still alive right now?

- Exactly ten thousand hours ago Bob had five friends. Does there exist a person **p** such that **p** was a friend of Bob ten thousand hours ago and **p** is currently dead.
- There is a specific set of five people who were, and maybe still are, my friends. I am uncertain whether all five people in set **A** are still alive or not.
- Are more than 50% of the people who were my friends ten-thousand hours ago still alive today?

Note that 50% is more closely related to the English word, "most" than 50% is related to other English words. For any person **p**, most of the friends of **p** are still alive if and only if more than 50% of the friends of **p** are still alive.